# How to get a dynamic value from a webpage using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a problem, I want to write a code in selenium C# (or another way) that getting dynamic value from a webpage (like clock) and display in my APP, The value of the variable within the webpage changes frequently and I want to display this value in my APP,I use a string variable to display value.

with below code:

```
string realTime= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='RealServerTime']")).Text;
```

but its a static text, and it does not display changes to the value of the variable, I don't really know that I can use selenium for this or not!? can everyone help me? thanks a lot

This is my code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Surena
{
    class Timing
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        public void clock(string textSend)
        {
            driver.Url = "http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15";
            string realTime= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='RealServerTime']")).Text;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: If that code works then just call it from a timer to get updates. It won't send you updates by itself. No selenium call will do that for you.

Comment: FindElement doesn't observe changes on the element, it just gets the element. As @rene says you will have to do something yourself to get the new value. Question is, do you really need to update it? Couldn't you just get the initial value and use the clock of your own machine to increment it? Or is that not precise enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **WebDriverWait** class to wait until given change and set condition that Text or other value change.

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm